# Current in a wire when electron accelerates

Tags: electric-current

Suppose electron in wire is accelerating isn't current same all over the wire? Thinking electrons as water molecule the current will be same all over the wire but the current will change as time changes. But why people say the current will not be constant over the wire if electron accelerate in wire? Why am I wrong?

Comment: You said “people say the current will …”. Please provide an exact quote and a link where we can see exactly who said that and the context in which they said it. The context matters

Comment: @Dale https://www.khanacademy.org/science/in-in-class-12th-physics-india/in-in-current-electricity/x51bd77206da864f3:drift-of-electrons-the-origin-of-resistance/v/drift-velocity-concept-intuition

Comment: He says electrons are accelerating, but the drift velocity is constant. On average the collective velocity of electrons is constant. The deceleration of collisions is equal to the acceleration due to the applied electric field

Comment: @CuriousMind you need to edit the question itself. Please put the link in, and make an exact quote. I skimmed through the transcript and did not find the exact quote in the question. With a video it is also helpful to put the time stamp in your question so that people answering do not need to watch the whole video to find the important part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: having read your question again,  when we say "the current is constant" we mean the current has no time dependence, aka is constant in time. You are referring to a constant spacial dependence. If electrons in the wire are macroscopically accelerating the current is not constant in time, but can be treated as constant in space as the entire wire has the same current (if the same wire ofcourse)

This is the drude model of conductivity, it models the electrons in a wire  with a resistive force proportional to its velocity

$m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}= q\vec{E} - \frac{m}{T}\vec{v}$

In the limit as t goes to infinity, the velocity is a constant, as the resistive force equals the electric force.

In this condition, $\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = 0$

Substituting into our differential equation

$0= q\vec{E} - \frac{m}{T}\vec{v}$

$\frac{m}{T}\vec{v}= q\vec{E}  $

$\vec{v}= \frac{Tq\vec{E}}{m} $

Meaning the velocity is constant.

Now substituting the definition $\vec{J} = nq \vec{v}$

We get

$\vec{J}= \frac{nTq^2\vec{E}}{m}$

Which is ohms law

Where $\frac{nTq^2}{m}= \sigma $

Comment: I think I got definition of current wrong. Is current of a wire charge/time through the whole wire or charge/time through cross section in wire?

Comment: Current at a point, is equal to the rate at which charge flows through a single cross section

Comment: so current at a point is current density and current of a wire is rate of charge over time through whole wire right?

Comment: Current density has units, current/area. And is defined as $\rho \vec{v}$  where $\rho$ is charge density( or Q/volume) and $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of the charge density. The relationship between current density and current is  current $= \iint \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da}$ . Which is the sum of current density * area, across a chosen cross section . Current is defined for a cross section of a wire. Not the whole wire

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now my doubt is clear.

Answer (score 2):

In the classical model of a conductor, the free electrons are in thermal equilibrium with the atoms and bounce rapidly and randomly off the atoms. In a uniform current carrying wire at equilibrium, the free charge density has a uniform gradient which produces a uniform electric field. This field accelerates the free electrons between each bounce giving rise to a small average drift velocity.